# Consequences of not showing up for one leg of journey

Tags: air-travel, usa, united-airlines

Recently I booked a flight using my points.
I am  planning to fly to Seattle WA from Indianapolis Indiana.  Stop over is Chicago.

On the day of my flight I am supposed to be in Chicago.   So I was wondering if I can directly board my Seattle flight from Chicago thereby not showing up in Indianapolis.

Is this okay?  Will United airlines cancel my entire journey if I do not show up in Indianapolis?

Comment: What on earth has this question got to do with the supposed duplicate?

Comment: @Berwyn no idea either, I've reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you have to take the second leg of a domestic flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-domestic-flight)

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud No it isn't!

Comment: @Berwyn Sorry, wrong one. Maybe a duplicate of this one http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27355/not-flying-the-first-leg-of-the-journey-company-cancels-the-second-leg-ticket#27359

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud I guess in a way. However that was asked two years after this one.

Answer (score 5):

Once you fail to board any flight on the itinerary, any later flights will be canceled.  So in your situation, when you do not board the IND-ORD flight, your ORD-SEA flight will be automatically canceled.

It's possible that if you do skip the first flight and simply try and board at Chicago that you will be able to talk them into re-instating your booking, but the only way you'll be able to do that is to lie to them and claim you did fly the IND-ORD leg and hope that they believe you, but keep in mind if you do this that :

- You will be lying, and possibly committing fraud.
- There's a good chance they will not believe you, and ORD-SEA is a long way to walk!
- You will not be able to check any bags
- You will need to check-in online, at least an hour before the IND-ORD flight departs

The only safe option is to change your ticket.  Depending on your status with United, this will cost you $75 (non-elite), $50 (Premier Silver), $25 (Premier Gold) or nothing (Premier 1K).