# How to get baggage at the carousel skipping connecting flight

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, airport-transfer

I had booked a return travel flight from Kolkata (CCU) to Hamburg (HAM) on 31. Oct 2015 via Jet Airways. The travel plan is from Kolkata (CCU) to Mumbai (BOM) and then to Brussels (BRU) and finally to Hamburg (HAM) after a 8 hours halt. I planned the trip with a halt to meet some friends in Brussels. But now I have to travel to Stuttgart (STU) on the same day due to official work. It is not possible to travel to Stuttgart after land in Hamburg as it would be too late. Also the airline doen't allow partial cancellation of flight.

Now what I want is, to book another flight from Brussels to Stuttgart on the same day without waiting in Brussels. For this I want my baggage at the Baggage carousel. The flight from Brussels to Hamburg is operated by Brussels Airlines and I think the baggage will be transported internally by Jet Airways and not sent to the baggage carousel.

What should I do, or where should I inform to get my baggage at the carousel in Brussels even though I have a connecting flight.

Comment: I think skipping the second leg of your flight might make them cancel your return ticket back to Kolkata.

Comment: @drat the answers given to http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/6711/1820 agree with you

Comment: You can insist that your baggage be returned to you—it's your bag, not theirs. But it may take several hours to be retrieved from the baggage pool (since it will be a low priority).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to go in your scenario is to *change* your flight, not to *partially cancel* your flight. As drat wrote, pretty much all airlines cancel your return flight if you do not show up for one leg of your flight, which you want to avoid.
Thus, you will need to get your ticket changed. Many airlines allow this on many fares if you do not change the countries of your trip.

Having said that, if you still want to get your bag in Brussels, you can ask the check-in agent at Kolkata to short-check it to Brussels. They do not always do that, but often do so if you state that you need something from your bag in Brussels due to the long lay-over. But as already said, if you miss the flight to Hamburg, your return trip ticket most likely will become void.

If for some reason you can't change your ticket destination from Hamburg to Stuttgart (e.g., if Jet Airways does not have bookable codeshare flights to Stuttgart), try rerouting it to Frankfurt instead. Frankfurt airport is ~1:15 hours away from Stuttgart by train.

Comment: Thanks @DCTLib for the response. I already tried to change my travel plan, but unfortunately they completely change the flight path. I also have my wife travelling with me to Hamburg, thats why I planned to fly together till Brussels. Since this is my return jorney, and I am not going back to Kolkata in the next 1 year, can I just skip the last flight, if I manage a short-check in Brussels? What I mean, is it a problem if the travel gets void?

Comment: That's hard to answer. It depends on the airline. Some try to charge the passenger the fare difference later. Others just ignore it. On flyertalk, people write that if you do this repeatedly, your frequent flyer account can be closed. So it is really hard to tell in advance. Note that you may be able to book a night train from Hamburg to Karlsruhe, which is only a short hop away from Stuttgart - perhaps taking that would allow you to fulfill your business obligations without changing your flight plans?

Comment: @dDebug Could you try just to cancel the last leg (saying you wanna stay in Brussels) and buy a low-cost from Brussels, or even a train? There's an ICE-ICE connection via Frankfurt. I would be expensive, but could be manageable.

Comment: @yo' I exatly tried to do this. But they said we cannot cancel a partial leg of the travel plan. It was weird but I can only listen!

Comment: @dDebug I suggest, hang up and try again. Call centre agents are notoriously bad at repricing a journey.

Comment: As far I know, cancelling the last leg would involve a complete rebooking: the original trip is Kolkata-Hamburg, and that would mean changing it to Kolkata-Brussels. Depending on the booked fare, this may not be possible or incur significant fees.