# Stopping for more than some hours in Dubai

Tags: air-travel, dubai, sydney, qantas

This is a follow-up to

[Flying from Dubai or London to Sydney](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64568/flying-from-dubai-or-london-to-sydney)

Can I enforce a full night stay between the two legs London-Dubai and Dubai-Sydney? Qantas or other airline.

Comment: what do you mean by enforce a full night stay? do you mean that you could make the schedule in a way that you would have at least a full night there? or do you mean that you could have the company paying you an hotel night there?

Comment: The schedule. And I would pay the room for myself. In the meanwhile I got info from Emirates how to reserve such a flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Emirates one can use Advanced Search, where you can specify any number of legs on a flight route, with dates you want.