# Avoiding the second leg of an international flight - different rates for a return ticket?

Tags: air-travel, united-airlines, price, swiss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you have to take the second leg of a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-flight)

I am in the process of booking a flight from LAX - ZUR. I found a flight for approx. 1100 USD. However, if I book that flight and then continue, after a 5 hour layover, onward to SVO, The flight is approx. half of the initial price, and the first leg of the second flight is the exact same flight as the first booking. Assuming I travel light and do not check any baggage, are there any potential issues with this? Seems like a hell of a way to save a good chunk of change.

Comment: There's no such airport as ZUR; do you mean [Zurich (ZRH)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZRH)?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of the above question.  The above question was regarding a domestic itinerary, where this is for an international itinerary.  The risks/benefits with hidden-city ticketing are very different for domestic v's international.

Answer (score 6):

Are you a Russian citizen, or have a Russian Visa?  If not, do not even attempt to do this.

When checking in for your initial flight the airport will most likely check that you are have the relevant paperwork to enter the countries on your trip.  In this case, that will include checking that you have a visa to enter Russia, and/or an onward ticket from Russia within a short period of time (if you are just transiting).

Presuming you don't have either of these, you will most likely not be allowed board even your first flight to Zurich.

"Hidden-city" ticketing as this is called can save money, but is frequently risky, especially for International trips.  In this case, it's not worth the risk that you will not be allowed to fly at all.

Comment: Don't recall anyone ever checking visa status at the departure airport.

Comment: Airlines check visa status on every single international flight.  To a large extent it's automated (Google for "auto doc check" for one of the main systems), but if the automated systems say you need a visa, they will ask about it.  If an airline lands you in a country where you need a visa and you don't have one, they can be charged a fine so they are pretty thorougher about it!

Comment: There is also the (admittedly somewhat remote given his departure point and username) possibility that OP's citizenship allows [visa-free entry into Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Russia).

Answer (score -2):

As @littleadv points out, your question might have been answered [elsewhere](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-flight).

However, your deduction is sound. If you don't check in luggage, there are no real repercussions.
You could be kind and cancel the second leg after you've arrived in ZUR, to avoid other travelers having to wait for someone who won't show up. :)

Comment: Flights aren't held for late passengers.