# Is fuel dumping a peculiarity of American airlines?

Tags: airlines, tips-and-tricks

[This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17993/1264) gave me some insight into the world of "fuel dumping", the technique of booking an irrelevant fare to avoid or remove a fuel surcharge.  The descriptions of it that I find on the web all seem to involve American airlines, so I was wondering whether this is a peculiarity of their booking and charge systems?

Australian fares tend to still have the fuel surcharge as significantly less than the base fare, for example, so I don't know if it would be worth it or even possible.  The Middle Eastern airlines tend to have lower fuel surcharges as well.  I don't know about Asian or European airlines.

Comment: As opposed to Australian airlines *physically* [dumping fuel](http://www.news.com.au/travel/travel-updates/qantas-flight-forced-to-dump-fuel-land-after-witness-claims-flames-came-from-engine/story-e6frfq80-1225847706376) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can happen with Australian airlines, but it is definitely rarer than the US ones - the fuel charges are lower and priced differently to the USA.

There's a [long thread on it on AustralianFrequentFlyer.com.au](http://www.australianfrequentflyer.com.au/community/cheap-international-airfares/discussion-of-fuel-dumps-49656.html) if interested, although it kinda deviates into an explanation of the concept anyway.

In general, it's still sometimes possible from Australia, eg some have managed to do it SYD-LAX, for example, although to be fair that was American Airlines.

Comment: (footnote, now you've got me reading all about it again and wondering about my upcoming trips...)

Comment: (for example post #28, shows one with the red roo airline)