# Clearing Customs and skipping connecting flight at ORD?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, transit, ord

I am coming back from Munich, connecting through ORD and onto Moline, IA. We have a 6 hour layover in Chicago but the drive to Moline is only 2. My question is this: After I clear immigrations and customs at ORD am I able to just leave the airport, rent a car and drive home? I have been told by some people you can do this and others have told me that if the customs agent sees that your bag tag reflects a connecting flight that they will make sure your bags get re-checked. Anyone know which is correct?

Comment: Related: [Do you have to take the second leg of a flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-flight)

Comment: Customs agents have nothing to do with checking bag tags, they are interested in other things.

Answer (score 9):

If your port of entry is ORD then that is where you will go through clearing customs irrespective of you having a connecting flight or not. Once you collect your bags and clear your customs check you are free to go wherever you want to go.