# Skip leg and book a connection with the same airline

Tags: air-travel

As part of a larger trip my last two flights are DFW-LHR and LHR-AMS. However, I would be a lot faster, if I skip the last leg and book an extra flight from London to my final destination.

My question: Can I run into problems, if the additional flight is with the same airline, which I have my original reservation with. If they checked, the would see, that I booked two different flights at almost the exact same time.

The original booking was an error fare, so trying to change it, is probably not the best idea either. Can anyone provide me with some ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Your travel agent might get an expensive ADM, and you might loose all your frequent flier points for the trip, or possibly have your frequent flier account cancelled. Unlikely to happen on a "first-offence" of dropping the last sector, but airlines are currently clamping down on it, especially on cheap X-LHR-Europe tickets. See [this long FlyerTalk thread for details](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/british-airways-executive-club/1731641-our-ex-eu-horror-story.html)

Comment: I seriously don't understand why would the regulators allow this kind of pricing... Selling a flight with more segments cheaper than the shorter one is clearly abusing the company's position in the market.

Comment: Another relevant question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20708/clearing-customs-and-skipping-connecting-flight-at-ord