# Can I pick up my luggage between flights with the same company?

Tags: luggage, transit, amsterdam, madrid, klm

I have a flight from Madrid to Aalborg with a stop in Amsterdam. The connection time betweeen the flight from Amsterdam and Aalborg it´s 1 hour and a half. The thing is that I want to stay in Amsterdam for a week and I want to pick up my checked in luggage at the Amsterdam airport. Can I do that if the flight it´s with the same company (KLM for instance) ?

I mean I can tell them that I want to pick up my luggage in Amsterdam right?

Comment: There's something I don't quite understand ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do you have to take the second leg of a flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-flight)

Comment: Possible but not sure. Rather than speculate, wait for yoyo to provide some more details.

Comment: So, yoyo, are you going to fly to Aalborg?

Answer (score 10):

What you are referring to is "short-checking" of bags - where your bags are only checked to an intermediate point along your journey.

Some airlines do allow short-checking of bags, although most will only allow it under specific circumstances, such as longer or overnight connections. Even airlines that used to allow it are starting to disallow it - for example, United Airlines recently updated their Contract of Carriage to specifically disallow short-checking.

Specifically for KLM, they do allow short-checking bags, however they charge a fee to do so - it used to be €225 per bag, although it may be higher now.  Even then, on such a short connection it's possible they will still say no, as the odds of you being able to collect your bags and make it back to the connecting flight is very low.

Comment: That's an insane amount of money for a short-check. You might as well use FedEx to your hotel

Comment: It's not that they are charging for the short-check, they are charging in an effort to stop people using hidden-city tickets.

Comment: Yes, if you are short-checking a bag with a 90-minute transfer time, it is pretty much telling the airline you are planning to skip the final segment. This is called a hidden city ticket because you really wanted to go to AMS but bought a ticket to Aalborg instead.