# What does the author mean by 'back to back' and 'hidden city' ticketing hacks?

Tags: air-travel, tips-and-tricks, terminology, hidden-city-ticketing

At this link about [travel hacks](http://thepointsguy.com/2014/09/8-travel-hacks-to-save-time-and-money/)

what does the author mean by this?

8. Back to back and hidden city ticketing. Sometimes airlines will charge far more for tickets to that do not include a Saturday night stay, on the assumption that those passengers are business travelers who aren’t flexible and can afford to pay more. Yet those who commute between cities eventually realize that they can purchase one round-trip ticket that covers their first outbound and last return, followed by round-trip tickets to return home on the weekends.

Comment: A roundtrip ticket, going on 1st of September, return on 30 September, and then little roundtrip tickets in between..

Comment: Thnaks but if my journey dates are 1st Sep and 30 Sep, what to do with the in between RT tickets?

Comment: it is for commuting people... like if you always go to the same place on weekly or daily basis for example. that's how I understand it. not sure I was totally correct.

Comment: Back-to-back ticketing and hidden city ticketing are two different ways of getting around air fare rules; Wikipedia's article on the matter is a decent enough overview: *[Airline booking ploys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys)*.

Answer (score 16):

**Hidden city ticketing**

Basically means buying a ticket A>M>Z where that is cheaper than A>M, but only going as far as M. Only works on singles (because the return would automatically be cancelled if the full booked route is not flown) and even so might not work after a few attempts (ie once the airline gets wind of the attempt to violate its rules, which do not allow this).

[Finding a hidden city route that indeed saves money generally requires many repeated airfare searches for many different destinations on an airline's web site.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys)

**Back-to-Back**

For a weekly commute, the column in the middle represents four ‘conventional’ tickets outbound to destination on Mondays and each returning ‘home’ on a Friday – none spans a Saturday so could be more expensive than otherwise:

[image: TSE36814 example]

On the right is one ‘conventional’ ticket but with the return one month later. However the commuter is not stuck at the destination meanwhile, since from there three weekly tickets ‘destination/home’ (the directions are reversed) should get the commuter to the right place at the right time, with each of the three spanning a Saturday and hence perhaps less expensive than otherwise.

One month is only for this example, such commuting may last years at a time.  [The usefulness of this strategy has diminished materially, as most airlines have abandoned the discount for a Saturday-night stay-over.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys)

Comment: "and even so might not work after a few attempts" - did you have any experience like that? Been doing this for many years myself.

Comment: Yeah, I heard "in general", that's why I asked if you had any experience :) I heard many times they "punish frequent fliers", but I'm Diamond on Delta, and never had any issues with this (nor even lost miles from the part flown). Would be interesting to sue an airline if they actually attempt to punish anyone.

Comment: Refusing to sell a ticket to someone who can end up being a black disabled veteran lady, and end up with a discrimination lawsuit with a potential to lose millions? Nah, I don't think their lawyers would approve that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52502/discussion-between-george-y-and-pnuts).