# Seoul-Toronto-Montreal, skipping last leg, what happens to my luggage?

Tags: transit, luggage, toronto, korean-air, westjet

Earlier this year I booked return tickets from Montreal to Seoul. The return flight is from Incheon to Toronto via Korean Air and Toronto to Montreal via WestJet.

The problem is I've now moved to Toronto and don't need the last flight to Montreal. Expedia said no need to cancel this portion of tickets, I can simply not show up.

But then what happens to my luggage? Can I book it to Toronto instead of Montreal? I heard airlines don't like throwaway tickets. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pick up my luggage between flights with the same company?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22916/can-i-pick-up-my-luggage-between-flights-with-the-same-company)

Comment: @Giorgio I don't think this is a duplicate, although it's very similar. The answers here suggest that the asker will have to collect their bags to go through customs at Toronto, which changes the situation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby fair enough; I'll remove the vote; ty.

Answer (score 23):

This is called *short-checking*. You can always ask but they do not always accept, particularly if your connection is short on time.

However in this case it does not matter. Even if they tag your luggage to YUL, you must take it through customs yourself when you enter Canada which is in Toronto for  you. At that point you will just be able to exit the airport with your luggage as you would do if you had a stopover in Toronto.

Comment: Note that if the transit were through YYZ terminal 1 it would probably not be the case that he would carry the luggage through customs. Terminal 1 now does airside transit for international arrivals, the bags are only called up if they decide to search them; he would need to short-check the luggage. His transit is in terminal 3, though, and it may be that in that terminal they still do it the old way (I'm not sure).

Comment: Perhaps for international to international, otherwise were does one go through customs? On arrival on the domestic flight in Montreal, he would not go through immigration or customs, so he must do these in Toronto.

Comment: In YYZ T1 there is a separate immigration channel for transit passengers and I understand the baggage handling system hangs on to your luggage until you pass that point. If the officer thinks your luggage needs inspection he'll send it and you to a baggage claim, otherwise he accepts your customs declaration, lets your luggage go to the onward flight and you stay airside. US preclearance customs works the same way now too.

Comment: That's new. Is that for terminal 1 arrival and departures? or just flights connecting in the same terminal? Given that two airlines are involved, it is possible the route in question requires a terminal change.

Comment: @Dennis: the "separate immigration channel for transit passengers" in Terminal 1 has been working only for arrivals from the US (unless things have changed very recently). Baggage, Air Canada transfers checked bagagge directly to the domestic connection but only for US and Europe arrivals. Source: my wife had to pick her bags at YYZ and re-check them five days ago.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will have to claim your luggage in Toronto anyway to go through customs so it should not be a problem.

To be double sure just glance at your luggage tag in Seoul and make sure that the tag says YYZ.

Comment: Wouldn't the tag say both YYZ and YUL on it?

Comment: @reirab Ah, with VIA YYZ. Living at a hub I don't see that much.