# Skipping the final leg in a multi-stop flight, will there be any immigration problems?

Tags: air-travel, usa, customs-and-immigration, airlines, mexico

I have a flight with 3 stops, the last one in Atlanta, before I arrive at México.

I was planning to stay a couple days in Atlanta, so I won't use  the last connection.

Since the cost to change the ticket is expensive I would rather to buy a new ticket just from USA to Mexico.

My question is, should I notify to the airline about this? Immigration in USA could see this action like suspicious?

Comment: Relevant/duplicate: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4440/2708

Comment: Yes, i have visa, that is not a problem

Comment: Bart, that's relevant but not a dupe, since it does not cover immigration.

Comment: Be sure it's not a round-tirp flight... if it is, your return flight will be completely cancelled when you miss one of the legs. So if you're hoping to pick up a return itinerary in Atlanta, you'll need to re-consider.

Comment: @Flimzy there is a US transit visa, and if that is what the OP has he would not be legal to remain in the US past a 'normal layover'. Visiting someone and/or seeing the sights is not allowed on a transit visa. he has not said what kind of visa or waiver, only that he has one.

Comment: @CGCampbell: My mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The airlines will not care; they might call out your name a few times - but they will consider you a no-show.

As far as immigration is concerned, as long as you have a valid visa for the US, they also do not care.

So, the answer to your question is:

1. No, you don't have to notify the airline.
2. The immigration will not have problems. They might ask you why you stayed, and if so, you should just tell them the truth.

The only thing that raises eyebrows is if you pay cash for a one-way ticket at the last minute. So, try to pay for your final trip online with a credit card or book it through an agent.

Comment: Ok, and I was thinking to buy return ticket before, not last minute. Thanks for your time.