# Not boarding at departure city

Tags: air-travel, legal

Can you book a flight from, say... San Diego to Cancun that has a plane change in L.A. and not board the flight in San Diego but rather in L.A.?  Say you "missed" your San Diego flight and were able to drive to L.A. in time for the flight from L.A. to Cancun, could you just go from there?  Some times flights are a lot cheaper leaving from one city as compared to another.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.  Essentially, you have to fly all legs of a trip.

IF you miss a leg, intentionally or otherwise, the airline assumes you can't make the other legs, and cancels all of them.

So while you may physically be able to drive to LA in time, you'd have been deemed to have missed the first leg, and there'll be no seat for you to Cancun.

It's known as hidden city ticketing, and we have quite a few other questions on it in different combinations, for example - [Do you have to take the second leg of a flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-domestic-flight?lq=1)

Comment: "The airline assumes you can't make the other legs, and cancels all of them" -- Not necessarily; if ticket rules permit, you may change the ticket, fly the first segment and then the remaining segments, too. The only 'hard' rule is that all segments must be flown in order.