# 3 passengers on a multi-city trip and 1 does not intend to take the last leg. Will the other 2 experience problems?

Tags: air-travel, tickets

We are three people going from Copenhagen-Philadelphia. I will be staying there because I have permission to work but the other two passengers need to go on to Rome within 20 days because they have permission only for tourism.

Buying one-way tickets Copenhagen-Philadelphia is much more expensive than buying multi-destination tickets Copenhagen-Philadelphia-Rome. I will not take the flight Philadelphia-Rome and do not care if I lose money for it as in any case it would be cheaper than one-way options.

My only concern is: might the other two passengers experience trouble at check-in because one passenger does not show up?

Comment: Why don't you just book separate tickets: one for you, and one for the two other passengers that will actually be flying back to Rome. Any decent travel agency will be able to make sure that the flight price won't go up by this (unless you get a group rate - but three people are not enough for this) by "holding" both tickets before actually confirming them. Then, the tickets would be unconnected and there is no need to worry. Having seperate tickets doesn't precluse you from sitting together on the plane.

Comment: Related: [Do I have to take the second leg of a domestic flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/4440/108) (Relevant even though that one was for domestic.)

Answer (score 1):

People miss flights all the time. As it is the last leg of your trip there is nothing the airline can do (normally they would cancel further flights) and as you have a visa immigration won't care that you didn't leave.

Don't advertize what is happening ( do not tell the airline checkin the whole story). If anyone asks, they do not know where Mr. Sole is.