# Miss my flight on purpose to get 24h layover at connecting city

Tags: bookings, cancellations, missed-flights

At the end of this month I have a flight from St. Lucia to New York and then New York to Phoenix where I live. There is a 24 hour layover in New York so I figured I would stay an extra day.

In order to change my flight and cancel the existing reservation to change it was about $500. I could book with a separate airline and it will cost a fourth of that. My question is:

If I miss my flight from New York to Phoenix and take a flight with a different airline, will I be OK?

Comment: Is it a one way ticket?  An have you checked with the airline on whether you can just cancel 1 leg?

Comment: Note that, if this is the first half of a round-trip flight, all subsequent flights on the same ticket will be cancelled once you miss the New York to Phoenix leg.

Comment: This is very close to something called "hidden-city ticketing" (except that in this case, the goal is usually to stay in New York, not to extend a stopover). Looking for that term will give you a lot of additional info, e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4440/do-you-have-to-take-the-second-leg-of-a-domestic-flight

Comment: You will lose all further legs on the ticket, including a potential return flight. Otherwise, no problems.

Comment: @Aganju: they may also confiscate some or all of your airmiles. Not sure how aggressively airlines do that these days.

Answer (score 6):

Since you have a 24 hour layover, there should be no real issues with missing the flight, you would simply be listed as a no show on the next day's NY to Phoenix flight and the airline pockets the fare.

Comment: Especially if it is a one way ticket, you won't have any issues missing the second leg.

Comment: Abusing sympathy by lying is a very effective way to make sure airlines will adopt even stricter policies telling employees not to be sympathetic.

Comment: @Tom Better, yes.

Comment: @Boris Only if it is a one way ticket.

Comment: The flight originates in Phoenix, then to st Lucia. Returning from St Lucia to new York to Phoenix. So last leg of trip would be missed. thank you for your answers.